# Check the render method of `PanelBody`

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, web

i have this issue in react , when i run my project, and i have no idea what to do.
this language is typescript

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `PanelBody`.

[image]

Comment: Please don't include your exception as an image. Have a read [of this](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Comment: Please add the code the for the `PanelBody` component to you question. Otherwise, we can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: i dont have any components for PanelBody , but i dont it says that